# How to Show Original "Cube" Around Subdivision Surface Modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

Following a tutorial and the instructor switches to the top Viewport to edit the object:

[image]

But when I try to do the same, I notice that the outline from the original cube which surrounded my subdivision surface modifier is now gone:

[image]

And I don't know how to get it back. Any way to get the original cube around the subdivision surface modifier to reappear? Like how it is when you first start a project in Blender?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the modifier's *On Cage* option, this option displays the edges as they would be if you applied the modifier :

[image]

Comment: The On Cage option is now disabled and yet the box still does not display: [https://i.imgur.com/yTUGUGk.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/yTUGUGk.jpg)

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: [https://pasteall.org/blend/0b8245eb8a764c7f94b76bc86be603c7](https://pasteall.org/blend/0b8245eb8a764c7f94b76bc86be603c7)

Comment: You've already subdivided it, so it's not a cube anymore, you must have already applied a Subdivision Surface?

Comment: Oh - yes I did apply a Subdivision Surface. So I guess after it's been applied, there's no showing the original cube anymore.

Comment: no, you've definitely lost the cube now